# Installing mongo_fdw

Tags: mongodb, postgresql

I am trying to install `mongo_fdw` on Ubuntu but I am getting some compilation errors. I have installed `mongodb`, `postgresql 9.1`, `postgresql-server-dev` and `libpq-dev` using apt-get.

I have updated the $PATH as instructed, cd to the directory with the mongo_fdw sources and typed make.

The code starts compiling but then I get errors (some objects and methods aren't found). What am I missing?

Comment: "Some compilation errors". "I get errors". **Always show exact error messages**. Also, PostgreSQL version? How you installed Pg? (From Ubuntu packages, from apt.postgresql.org, other). Distro & version should always be listed too. Please **edit your question** to add the info, and comment here when done so I get a message.

Comment: I added details, with regards to the errors the thing that struck me the most is that when make CDed to the driver directory it said that there was nothing to do for "all"

Comment: Also I'm using the latest version of ubuntu (13), I'll be trying with an earlier version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the extension you're using expects the 9.2 version of the foreign data wrapper API, which has read/write support. Without details like exact errors it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Tried it with version PostgreSQL 9.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.3 and it worked :) I had to run scons in the driver directory for it to work even though the documentation says it's only required for windows